# Can box2d track my Cocos2d actions of sprites?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I just started using Cocos2D this week. While playing around with Box2d i was wondering if it was possible to **move CCSprites with the help of CCActions** and use **box2ds collisiion detection** feature to detect collision between those sprites..

I'm pretty sure this must be possible?

Comment: what kind of collision? If rectangle/circle collision boundaries suffice, physics engine is overkill. If you need to trace shapes of a sprite to get collision poly you'll need PhysicsEditor as well. Pixel perfect collisions? Again, no physics engine can do that well.

Comment: Hey it's about a sprite/poly collision. Didn't know pixel perfect collisions weren't possible. Is it because of the conversion error from m to px? What about calling CoreGraphics intersection methods from within my Cocos tick callback for collision detection?

Comment: a physics engine has no concept of graphics, so it can't possibly know about the pixels representing one of your game objects. Instead you'll have to approximate shapes with polygons and with as few vertices as possible, this is a crucial performance matter. Box2D allows polygons to have no more than 8 vertices for example.

Comment: oh yes, of course, thank you. thought you were speaking of pixel perfect collision between shapes. love your site btw :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need real physics behavior, I'd highly recommend to "manually" deal with your collision logic. That said, for your scenario I would start with this approach.-

- Create one body per sprite, and assign each sprite to the user data.
- Your 'static' scenario would map to static bodies (i.e floor, platforms, etc...)
- Your 'dynamic' sprites would map to dynamic bodies, which only fixture would be marked as sensor
- You'd register a b2ContactListener to listen for the collisions.
- As for the tricky part, you'd need to set in each iteration of the main loop, the position of each body to the position of each sprite (of course, translating pixels to meters), in order to avoid that they just behave as physics bodies. You could try just to not calling world->step, but not sure if contactListener would work then.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank You very much. Yes, manually adjust the sprites position, was also the only possibility i could think of. Hm. Maybe i'll do some physics and move my sprite by applying some forces. BTW: I definitely need physics behaviour for my character, but want to move my platform with CCAction..